# Alternating and iterating through multiples iterators of different lengths without stopping

Tags: python, exception, iteration

Here is an example:

```
for i in f('abcde','fg','hijk'):
print(i,end='')
#should print out
afhbgicjdke
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
def f(*args):
    arg_list = [argument for argument in args]
    iter_list = []
    for arg in arg_list:
        iter_list.append(iter(arg))

    try:
        while True:
            for i in iter_list:
                yield next(i)
    except StopIteration:
        iter_list.remove(i)
        for i in reversed(iter_list):
            yield next(i)
```

With the same example this is what I am printing out:

```
afhbgicjd
```

i can't figure out how to handle this StopIteration error. I am trying to implement this without using itertools

Answer (score 2):

This is an application for [izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

```
from itertools import chain, izip_longest
''.join(chain.from_iterable(izip_longest('abcde', 'fg', 'hijk', fillvalue='')))
```

Output:

```
'afhbgicjdke'
```

In this example it zipped the three sequences into tuples of three elements. If there wasn't a corresponding element for one of our sequences, we used a default value of `''`. Then we flattened those tuples using `chain.from_iterable` and we finally joined all the characters together.

If we are allowed only to use basic functions, we could do it like this:

```
def f(*args):
    n = len(args)
    iters = map(iter, args)
    exhausted = [False] * n
    while n > 0:
        for i, it in enumerate(iters):
            if not exhausted[i]:
                try:
                    yield next(it)
                except StopIteration:
                    exhausted[i] = True
                    n -= 1

print ''.join(f('abcde', 'fg', 'hijk'))
```

With this code we keep track of the exhausted iterators. When the number of *live* ones reaches to zero, we stop our generator. If an iterator is exhausted, then we don't check it next time.

Comment: I am trying to implement this without itertools

Comment: dustinyourface: In Python 3, it's called `zip_longest()`. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) provides a pure Python equivalent to it (so does the Python 2 documentation for `izip_longest()`. Same for `chain()`.

Comment: @dustinyourface if you don't mind me asking, why don't you want to use itertools? It's in the standard library, it's there for you to use without fear.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution that doesn’t use itertools or zipping (and also doesn’t try to embed the zipping implementation):

```
def f (*args):
    maxLen = max(map(len, args))
    for i in range(maxLen):
        for arg in args:
            if i < len(arg):
                yield arg[i]
```

---

For any iterable:

```
def f (*args):
    args = [iter(arg) for arg in args]
    while True:
        yielded = False
        for arg in args:
            x = next(arg, None)
            if x is not None:
                yielded = True
                yield x
        if not yielded:
            break
```

```
>>> list(f(range(3), range(3, 5), range(5, 10)))
[0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: These don't yield the values in the desired order.

Comment: Thanks this info was useful but I am trying to alternate. See example.

Comment: Oops, I wasn’t reading the question correctly. Changed my answer.

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly the map method is doing? And why are you checking if i < len(arg)?

Comment: `map(len, x)` applies the `len` function to every element of `args`. So it essentially gives you a sequence of the lengths of all arguments. So `max()` on that gives you the maximum length, which is the maximum number of iterations we need to do to get the very last item from the longest argument. The check `i < len(arg)` is there to prevent an index error for arguments which are not long enough. At that point, we have consumed them completely, so we can skip them.

Comment: This would not work if an argument was an iterable that len() can't be called on  right? Like range(x,y)?

Comment: Yes, `len` is the lesser problem though; it uses index access later.

Answer (score 0):

This is [a recipe in the `itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

For example, using the `IPython` REPL:

```
In [19]: from itertools import *

In [20]: def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
   ....:                     

In [21]: "afhbgicjdke" == "".join(roundrobin('abcde','fg','hijk'))
Out[21]: True
```

Comment: I saw in a comment to an answer that the OP is trying not to use `itertools`... Having said that the proper place for such statement is the body of the question (or, maybe, the question's title itself) I don't remove my answer as I see it as a sort of direction post pointing to the excellent documentation of `itertools` and the large numbers of recipes that have been collected there.